# Registration with Gigya Swift SDK code verification email not being sent

Tags: swift, react-native, gigya

Working on writing a bridge function for registering a new user in Gigya. Or registration flow is set to send a code verification email on registering a new user. This seems to not be firing when registering via the Swift SDK. Am I missing something in the way we are sending the request?

swift...

```
@objc(registerAccount:password:params:resolve:rejecter:)
  func registerAccount(email: String, password: String, params: [String : Any],
                       _ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                       rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    self.gigya.register(email: email, password: password, params: params) { result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let data):
        resolve(data);
      case .failure(let error):
        switch error.error {
        case .gigyaError(let data):
          resolve(data.toDictionary())
        default:
          reject("E_REGISTER_ACCOUNT", "Registration failed", error.error)
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

objc...

```
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(registerAccount:(NSString *)email
                  password:(NSString *)password
                  params:(NSDictionary *)params
                  resolve:(RCTPromiseResolveBlock)resolve
                  rejecter:(RCTPromiseRejectBlock)reject)
```

and lastly this gets called by JS...

```
export async function register() {
  const email = 'test-registration@purple.com';
  const password = '234567';
  const req = await GIGYA_MANAGER.registerAccount(
    email,
    password,
    {
      finalizeRegistration: true,
      profile: {
        email: email,
        firstName: 'Stella',
        lastName: 'Beaglesmith'
      }
    }
  ).catch((err) => console.log(err));
  return req;
}
```

I am able to see new users created in the sites identity access tab, but no code verification email seems to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming across this in the future. When registering via the API, you need to send the verification manually so in Swift you will have a method that looks like this...

```
@objc(resendVerificationCode:regToken:resolve:rejecter:)
  func resendVerificationCode(UID: String, regToken: String,
                              _ resolve: @escaping RCTPromiseResolveBlock,
                              rejecter reject: @escaping RCTPromiseRejectBlock) -> Void {
    self.gigya.send(api: "accounts.resendVerificationCode", params: [
      "UID": UID,
      "regToken": regToken
    ]) { result in
      switch result {
      case .success(let data):
        print(data.values)
      case .failure(let error):
        print(error)
      }
    }
  }
```